# How do I stop webpacker from rebuilding on demand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I've been hunting through the Webpacker Gem for hours but I cannot find the mechanism that actually does the on demand compiling in Webpacker. Basically every time I run a request I am having a 90 second wait time while web packer rebuilds.

This is unnecessary as I am running it separate from Rails. There should be a hook or someplace in the code that it says "Hey I can't find the server, let me rebuild".

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT/NOTE: I'm only asking in relation to the dev environment.

Comment: Is it in development environment?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh Yes it is. I'll amend the question

Answer (score 2):

In `webpacker.yml` have you tried setting `compile` and `hmr` options to `false`

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: false
  dev_server:
    ...
    hmr: false
    ...
```

After changing the settings, restart your server. Give it a try.